# Ajax script not working on Form Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue, I am loading a partial page however I dont want the form on this page to redirect when I click the save button.

Not sure if I am using the script the correct way, I want to Post to the controller when I click submit but I want to be redirected back to the same page I was on (`AdminPanel/AdminProfile`) and not redirected to a different controller/view (`Account/Manage`).

AdminProfile View:

```
                    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
                           @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Account/Manage.cshtml");
                           }
                    </div>
```

Not sure if my script should go in this view or stay in the partial view?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
{
    //....
    return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel") });
}
```

Partialview with script:

```
@model LocalPasswordModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
}
<section class="hgroup">
    <div class="panel-body">       
        <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right top-right">
            <li>You're logged in as <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="message-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</ul>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SavePassword", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        <div class="social_sign">
            <h3>Change your password.</h3>
        </div>
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        @Html.ValidationSummary()
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Old Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control"})
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12 col">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Change password" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

    }
    </div>
</section>
```

Script in the view above:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#SavePassword').submit(function () 
        {
            if ($(this).valid()) 
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) 
                    {
                        if (result.redirectTo) 
                        {
                            window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            $(".tab-2").html(result);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () 
                    {

                    }
                });
          }
    })
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Nothing seems to happen all I get is an empty page with `{"redirectTo":"/AdminPanel/AdminProfile"}` in it. Which is the url: `http://localhost:57239/Account/Manage`

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` from event handler inside `if` statement

Comment: You mention inside the if statement the answer below says it is outside the if?

Comment: The validation plugin will by default prevent the form submission if the form is invalid, you need to stop page redirection only when the form is valid and you want to POST data using _ajax_

Comment: is making the submit button just a regular button, and handling the click event instead of submit event out of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your code like these:

```
<script>
    $('#SavePassword').submit(function () 
    {
        if ($(this).valid()) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) 
                {
                    if (result.redirectTo) 
                    {
                        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $(".tab-2").html(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function () 
                {

                }
            });
      }

     return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: add return false in end of your function

Comment: does the same. Still redirects me to the Account/Manage page which then returns the Json data.

Answer (score 1):

You have already attached the AJAX call, but forgot to prevent the default submission event. So, use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#SavePassword').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Rest of your code.
  if ($(this).valid())
```

Comment: Still sends me to the same page.

Comment: When clicking the submit I only have one error on the page it redirects me to `no element found` it is still redirecting me to the Account/Manage view. I dont have a live url at the moment. This has been giving me a headache for 4 days now.

Comment: @GarrithGraham Keep the preserve log button checked. And tell me what all do you see?

Comment: What is the preserve log button and where do I find it in Firefox?

Comment: @GarrithGraham Can you try using Chrome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92736/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-garrith-graham).